# how to control interval of for loop?

Tags: php

I have a for loop, with a $count of 23.

```
for($page=0; $page < $count; $page++) { 
echo $page;
}
```

What I want to do is instead of increasing the page variable by one, I want to do it by 10 so that when $page is echoed it I want the results to be 10, 20, and not go past 23.

```
for($page=0; $page < $count; $page+10) { 
echo $page;
}
```

When I do this, the loop continues infinitely, echoing 0. IF anyone has any advice, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$page+10` statement do not alter $page variable. Change it to one that does it

Comment: lol. thanks colonel... The reason I posted was because I did not know what to change it to.

Comment: you do not know how to write `$page=$page+10`? Really?

Comment: yeah I do, but it did not occur to me, since I have little experience using for loops, hence the question being posted. Anyway, thanks for your insight, appreciate it.

Comment: I didn't question reasons made you post. I merely tried to explain why your code didn't work and show you the way to solve.

Comment: It's all good man, it is sometimes hard to interpret what people's intentions are when you try to interpret text comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for($page=0; $page < $count; $page+=10) { 
  echo $page;
}
```

Just got your increment syntax a bit wrong (should have been page `+=` not page `+` which doesn't actually update the value of the `$page` var)

Alternatively you can use the long form/more complex mathematics:

```
for($page=0; $page < $count; $page=$page+10) { 
  echo $page;
}
```

**word of caution** make sure you stick with a ranged condition (`<` or `<=`) if you're switching your step size like this, otherwise you can jump past your condition (if it read `!=23` for example) and create a never ending loop.  Not a problem for you the way you wrote it, but just something to consider.

Comment: when you say reset, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed that typo, it should have been update not reset... this code will increment the value of page by 10 each time, you could also write it long-hand as `$page=$page+10` (or use other mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<?PHP 
$count = 23;
for($page=0; $page < $count; $page++) { 
if ($page % 10 == 0 && $page != 0)
    echo $page."</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe, $page += 10 more easy?